# Merging rows from a csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, tidyr

I have a csv file from a database in the following form and trying to import with "read.csv" command into into R for statistical analysis.

```
    ID var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6
   1   one   one   one   one   one
  NA   one         one   one   one
  NA   one         one   one      
  NA               one   one      
  NA               one            
   2   two   two   two   two   two
  NA   two   two   two         two
  NA   two   two   two         two
  NA   two         two            
  NA   two                        
  NA   two                        
  3 three three three three three
  4  four  four  four  four  four
 NA  four  four  four        four
 NA  four  four  four        four
 NA              four        four
 NA              four            `
```

The csv file has records of many subjects with 6 column variables, but for demonstration purpose I have taken data of 4 persons. The variables var1, var2... etc are basically text data and are  overflowing to next rows depending on the number of characters in that particular variable. There is no particular pattern to how many rows the are overflowing to. The next subject's data is starting after the last observation of previous subject.
Because of this variability, the csv file has more than three thousand rows even though the number of subjects are around 100.

There is now way to concatenate the rows in the original database.
Can anyone suggest a way get all the records in a single row with each variables' data? I am regular visitor to stackoverflow for R related issues and so far found solutions to every other issue I had and this is the first time I got stuck. Looks like a unique problem!

Edit: There are no rows which are completely empty all the way. I could not post image of the files as I don't have enough reputation!

The data I have posted is of 4 subjects only but as you can see it runs into 17 rows both in csv and after reading into R. as I tried explained in original post `var1`... `var6` are "text" type of data and for some reason after it maxes out it overflows to next row in csv with empty values for `ID` and other `var(n)` which have shorter texts. The next subject's record starts after the last row of longest `var(n)`. I hope that explains the problem.

Comment: I don't understand where the var1 ends and var2 begins in case of 1, 2 and 4. Could you make that a bit more clear?

Comment: If your data contains many empty rows you should just consider removing them? What's the point in merging several empty rows? To be honest, it's not clear to me what you wish to perform. Can you post a sample matrix that would depict the output that you desire?

Comment: If you have no idea how theoretically we could separate the contents corresponding to each field for a given person... and we don't see the data... I'm not sure how we can come up with a solution (since indeed it doesn't look like a standard issue). Can you upload the data (or say the first 50 lines) somewhere and provide us with a link?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6aQB3rSaYiCSXRXZUc3NkVGY2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi I have posted the link to the test csv file in google drive

Comment: If possible I would tidy this data so its easier to perform analysis.  Tidy Data: https://ramnathv.github.io/pycon2014-r/explore/tidy.html - it has to standardise to an R dataframe to get much further.